# Как узнать сколько денег на счете сим карты в gsm модеме, Arduino?

Tags: arduino

Скажите, пожалуйста, как в arduino вы можете узнать, сколько денег на SIM-карте в gsm модеме. Я знаю команду AT ("AT+CUSD=1,\"#100#\""), но я не знаю, **как записать ответ на переменную**. Помогите сделать это.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вопрос был решён довольно давно.. но вдруг кому-то пригодится

```
 char inputGsmFullArr[200] = {0}; //массив для хранения всей смс
short int indxGsm = 0; // счетчик символов для буфера
String inputGsmFullStr = ""; //входящая строка с gsm модема - полная
bool flagGsmActive = false;
char ch = NULL;

void loop()
{
  while (gprsSerial.available())
  {
    delay(1);
    flagGsmActive = true;
    byte c = gprsSerial.read();
    inputGsmFullArr[indxGsm++] = c;
    logger.LogPrintBytes(c);
  }
  if (!gprsSerial.available() && flagGsmActive)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < indxGsm; i++)
    {
      inputGsmFullStr += inputGsmFullArr[i];
    }
    ReadGsmStr(inputGsmFullStr);
    ClearBufferArray(inputGsmFullArr, indxGsm);
    indxGsm = 0;
    flagGsmActive = false;
    Serial.flush();
    gprsSerial.flush();
  }
}

void ClearBufferArray(char *array, short int sizeBuf) // function to clear buffer array
{
  for (byte i = 0; i < sizeBuf; i++)
  {
    array[i] = NULL;
  }
}

//Обработка смс приемника-передатчика
//----------------------------------
boolean isStringMessage = false; //Флаг, что данные с GSM содержат текстовое сообщение
String lineFullStr = ""; // Входная строка построчно из inputGsmFullStr
String currNumTmp = "";
//----------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void ReadGsmStr(String fullGmsStr)
{
  //Очистили подстроку главной строки
  lineFullStr = "";
  //Читаем посимвольно нашу полную СМС и выдергиваем оттуда подстроки
  //А вид она имеет следующий  \r\n +CMT: "+79999999999","NAME","16/01/28,00:36:38+24" \r\n
  //                            1234567890 \n
  //                            1234567890 \r\n
  for (int i = 0; i < fullGmsStr.length(); i++)
  {
    //Если находим символ возврата каретки
    if (fullGmsStr.charAt(i) == '\r')
    {
      // если это продолжение полной смс - само тело без заголовка - 1234567890 \n - то обрабатываем то что внутри (команды)
      if (isStringMessage)
      {
        lineFullStr.toUpperCase();

        CheckGsmSubString(lineFullStr);

        isStringMessage = false;
      }
      else
      {
        CheckGsmSubString(lineFullStr);
      }
      lineFullStr = "";
    } 
    else if ('\n' != fullGmsStr.charAt(i))
    {
      lineFullStr += fullGmsStr.charAt(i);
    }
    else if ('\n' == fullGmsStr.charAt(i))
    {
      lineFullStr += '\n';
    }
  }
  inputGsmFullStr = ""; //Очищаем то что пришло с GSM
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void CheckGsmSubString(String gsmSubStr)
{
  // если это текстовое сообщение
  if (StringContains(gsmSubStr, "+CMT"))
  {
    //Парсим смс
  }
  // если это звонок
  else if (StringContains(gsmSubStr, "+CLIP"))
  {
    //Парсим звонок
  }
  // этот блок отлавливает ответ на запрос баланса и отправляет его смской
  else if (StringContains(gsmSubStr, "+CUSD"))
  {
    IsRequestBalanceFromGsm(gsmSubStr);
  }

  //---------------------КОМАНДЫ----------------------------
  // делаем запрос баланса (мтс), ответ ловится +CUSD
  else if (StringContains(gsmSubStr, "BAL"))
  {
    gprsSerial.println("ATD#100#");
  }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// запрос баланса и отправляет его смской +CUSD
void IsRequestBalanceFromGsm(String str)
{
  str = str.substring(str.indexOf("Balance"), str.indexOf("r"));
  delay(1500);
  str += " is your balance of number " + currentNumber;
  SendSms("ТУТ НОМЕР НА КОТОРЫЙ ОТПРАВЛЯТЬ ОТВЕТ", str);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
const char q = (char)34; // символ "
const char r = (char)13; // символ возврата каретки (Enter)
const char z = (char)26; // передача ^Z
// Функция отправки смс
void SendSms(String number, String text)
{
  logger.LogPrintlnStr("SEND SMS FUNC RETURN: ");
  logger.LogPrintlnStr("NUMBER: " + number + "\nTEXT: " + text);
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CMGD=4"); //удалить все сообщения на сим карте
  delay(1500);
  gprsSerial.print("AT+CMGS="); // send the SMS the number
  gprsSerial.print(q); // передача в порт символа "
  gprsSerial.print(number); // передача номера телефона
  gprsSerial.print(q); // передача в порт символа "
  gprsSerial.print(r);
  delay(1500);
  gprsSerial.println(text); // передача текста сообщения
  delay(500);
  gprsSerial.print(z); // передача ^Z
  gprsSerial.print(r); // передача Enter
}
```